# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.linear_model' has no attribute 'LinearRegression'

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to `import 'from sklearn import linear_model'`,but showing me error like this:-

> AttributeError: module 'sklearn.linear_model' has no attribute
>   'LinearRegression'

Comment: are you getting the error on the import statement?

Comment: show your complete code and steps followed also please read [mcve] and follow it in every next post

Comment: are you using the LinearRegression like this? ```reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()```